# How could I simplify a pattern tile with A LOT of repeated mini squares?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, patterns, transform, tiles

I'm designing a nonwoven fabric (the panels size will be 69"x92"). The repeat tile measures 21"x21" and I need to repeat mini squares that measure 1/32" each. Above the layers containing these mini squares, the pattern tile will have other elements.

I designed the squares and then repeated them using Effect --> Distort&Transform --> Transform. As you can imagine, the anchor points are too many: my RAM is almost exploding and I really need to find another solution. Repeating the final pattern would be impossible.

I tried to simplify the path with Object -->Path-->Simplify, but it's not enough.

Do you have any suggestions?

I should also specify that I'm repeating these little squares in order to give a "fabric texture" effect to a nonwoven fabric. Any other ideas to recreate a woven effect would be more than welcome.
[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually creating a repeating pattern, as opposed to duplicating the object a bunch of times?

First, create a bit of squares that you want to repeat.

[image: squares]

Then, go to Object > Pattern > Make

[image: menu]

This will bring up the pattern options.

[image: options]

Once your pattern is created, you will see it in the swatches panel.

[image: swatches]

Then you only need to create a large rectangle and fill it with your pattern.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Patterns are definitely the way to go. I created [this single tile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJRFy.png) and [used it to create a pattern](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wbYx0.png) then overlayed that on [these colored squares](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5aLo4.png) for [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/koCLq.png). Illustrator is much better at rendering patterns than it is duplicated objects.

Comment: Hi John, thank you very much for your help and your detailed answer. I'm familiar with this process, in fact, the big square you see will eventually become a pattern tile. I prefer to avoid creating "patterns inside of patterns". I  know how to overcome the old "patterns cannot contain anything painted with a pattern" problem but, even if composed of many patterns, I'm not sure the final tile would be RAM-friendly.

Comment: Hoooly moly JohnB. You changed my day. Thank you both for your prompt replies and your amazing help.

Comment: @Erica it sounds like you've already got it figured out, but in case anyone else stumbles across this question looking for the same: you can create a separate pattern for the texture and the colors and it'll be RAM-friendly. I applied mine to a 10,000px² shape; Illustrator didn't break a sweat.

Comment: @JohnB thanks again. You really saved me.  Just a last thing: on that tile I'll need to place other elements (leaves). Do you think it will be a problem?  To overcome the "pattern inside a pattern" trouble, I usually design the elements on a separate artboard (leaves, in this particular case), and then, while I'm on pattern-editing mode, I paste them on the tile.

Comment: @Erica there are always going to be a few ways to accomplish things, but for your situation I would just keep stacking new pattern fills on top of your shape. So you could create a third pattern on top of the coloring and texture to add leaves (or in this quick example, stars: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cddCU.png)